# Why won't the Music App launch?

Tags: music, crash, apps, launcher

For the last few days, the Music App won't launch. I click on the icon, it appears in the dock, opens a window and closes down straight away, without giving me the chance to see what's happening. Any clue? 
Thanks!

---

After today's eOS update, it worked again, then now is back to failing to launch, again.

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround here:
https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/391

It crashes on startup if an NTFS partition is mounted.

I unmounted all network shares and it doesn't crash on startup for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to eOS SE. Please follow these steps and answer the questions,

1. Is the problem happening with a **particular file or type**?
2. Can you play those file with any other music player?
3. Do you have Ubuntu's **default media codecs** installed?

If you want to install default media codecs, please execute this command in the terminal. If your problem is caused by missing codec than this will help.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you want to try another music player you can try `vlc`. Get it by executing,

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Thanks, other files open without problems, and I already use VLC and rhythmbox